# Vfr Reader Right to Left reading

Tags: ios, pdf, right-to-left

I am a newbie in iPhone development. I am currently working on an Arabic iPhone application which has PDF files to read. I am currently using vfr/Reader open source reader which works as per expectations. Now the client wants the PDF documents to be read (scrolled) from right to left or in opposite direction. I tried everything but couldn’t get it. Can someone please lead me to in right direction or share some sample code.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show [the code you have so far](http://whathaveyoutried.com).  You should include at least an outline (but preferably a [mcve]) of the code that you are having problems with, then we can try to help with the specific problem. You should also read [ask].

Answer (score 0):

The only right-to-left reader for iOS that I am aware of for iOS is called CloudReaders which is free in iTunes Store.

Maybe the author of that app can advise you

Answer (score 0):

You can transform (Rotate) the main view of Reader which is ScrollView by (`M_PI`) as this `theScrollView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI);`

then make rotation to the content view by (`-M_PI`) as This :

```
contentView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(-M_PI);
```